# Restrict google autocomplete output to city only

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, google-api

I have the following code to look for cities from a given country using the google auto complete api:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=KEY&sensor=false&libraries=places&region=uk" type="text/javascript"></script>

     function initialize() {
       var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
       var options = {
         types: ['(cities)'],
         componentRestrictions: { country: "uk" }
     };
       var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
     }
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have added region in the script src so as not to include the country in the output.
For example, if I type Lo, I get London only and not London, UK

However since I am getting the country, its ISO code, from a dropdown, I need to be able to change both the componentRestrictions and the region in the google api  URL.
Any idea how to do that?  I know I can get the country selected from the dropdown as below:

```
var country= $('#CountryDropdown');
```

How do I pass the var country to the componentRestrictions and the region?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by this.
Hope this will help you.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Yourkey&v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

function initialize() {

    var input = document.getElementById('FullAddress');
    var options = {
        types: ['address'],
        componentRestrictions: { country: 'uk' }
    };
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        for (var component in componentForm) {
            document.getElementById(component).value = '';
            // document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
        }
        $("#Latitude").val(place.geometry.location.lat());
        $("#Longitude").val(place.geometry.location.lng());

        // Get each component of the address from the place details
        // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work.  when I debug it, I can see that it does not enter the code : google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {... Any idea why?